# Accessing a public final constant in another class?

Tags: java, oop, object, constants

I'm trying to access a constant in java that's stored in "Constants.java", a private class, and use it in another to evaluate it in a method.

I'm not allowed to change the Constants class, and the constant I'm trying to accessed is initialized in the following way:

```
 public final int INVENTORY_MAX = 100;
```

I tried the following:

```
 if (h <= Constants.INVENTORY_MAX)
```

But Constants is private and without it, it's asking me to make a local variable. I also would make the variable static, but the code is given by the professor and I cannot change it in any way. Please help!

Thank you.

EDIT: The following is a screenshot that shows that the Constants class is private. Ignore the error message under Constants.

[Class Constructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBVd3.png)

[Constants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Niwrs.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > I would, but the Constants class if given by my professor that is not allowing >me to change the Constants class.
>
> There is also this method in his code that may be useful:
>
> ```
> public static Constants getInstance() {
>      if(instance == null)
>          instance = new Constants();
>      return instance;
> }
> ```
>
> Per your edit `Constants` is a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), so first get the instance and then access the field directly.

```
INVENTORY_MAX = 100;
Constants consts = Constants.getInstance(); // new Constants();
// ...
if (h <= consts.INVENTORY_MAX)
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect solution to my problem.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:**
It does not say class is private, it is saying constructor is private. Which means you cannot create an instance of the class outside of it.

So you do the following:

```
Constants consts = Constants.getInstance();
if (h <= consts.INVENTORY_MAX)
```

Comment: I would, but the Constants class if given by my professor that is not allowing me to change the Constants class.